# ASP.NET NameValueCollection Empty despite POST being visible in Wireshark

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have run into a problem. This is my environment:
Visual Studio 2015
ASP.NET Solution and using IIS Express for debugging purposes.

I am using Chrome's Postman to submit POST data to my application and despite seeing the form data in Wireshark, I am unable to see the data within my Request object in the Page.Load for the page that is being hit.

What could I be missing?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why I got a negative vote for my question. Would appreciate knowing why?

However, I wanted to let you know that I did resolve my problem and it was specific to the RouteConfig.cs solution and how FriendURLs were implemented.

My original Routconfig.cs was:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
}
```

I was finally able to get post data using the following instead:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
}
```